# Tor not connecting to relays

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, connection

Log:

26-Jun-18 10:49:10 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

26-Jun-18 10:49:10 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

26-Jun-18 10:49:10 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

26-Jun-18 10:49:10 AM.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
26-Jun-18 10:49:11 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

26-Jun-18 10:49:14 AM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

26-Jun-18 10:49:15 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection

26-Jun-18 10:49:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus

26-Jun-18 10:49:16 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus

26-Jun-18 10:49:22 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network

26-Jun-18 10:49:22 AM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:23 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:24 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:25 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:26 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:27 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:28 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:29 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:30 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:31 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:32 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:33 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:34 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:35 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:36 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:37 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:38 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:39 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:40 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:41 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:42 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:43 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

26-Jun-18 10:49:44 AM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I see same problem. Is particularly a problem when using obfs4 (and 3) bridges. They seem to be blocked or directed towards specific obfs entry points. 
Use another bridge method e.g. fte or meek until obfs method is restored